# von Neumann entropy of an arbitrary composition system

Tags: entanglement, entropy

I understand the von Neumann entropy of a $2$-composite system is that of the [reduced density matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement#Reduced_density_matrices)? What is the von Neumann entropy of an entanglement of a more than $3$ composite system?

Comment: sorry, I misread. Yes, the entanglement entropy is the von Neumann entropy of the reduced state. For multipartite states it's not so simple to quantify entanglement, however. See e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/506762/58382, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/16181/55, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/184426/58382, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipartite_entanglement